# Submit regular news content aggregator iOS app as a Newsstand app, allowed?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, newsstand-kit

Is it allowed/valid to publish a news application as a newsstand app? An app being developed is basically a kind of news article aggregator across certain genres while also allowing users to share/favorite/filter content within the app. Since this seems and is in fact more like a regular table listing to webview detail display application instead of one's that display say magazines or pdf content for instance, i'm confused if it was ok to submit such an app as a newsstand app since it caters to a certain niche of news app users (client idea). The app content would be created and managed by the client organization so it wont just be a random feed grabber of stuff online. Also there wont be any subscriptions via `IAP` or usage of any newsstand stuff apart from marking the app as a newsstand app. Will this lead to rejection? Additionaly, newsstand apps get their newsstand display icons from the newly updated content (like periodically published magazines) while this app is more of a regular kind so i'm unaware how the icon display should/would happen or work? Any help & references to guidelines is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your app description I think this will definitely get rejected by Apple. Subscription availability, periodical (not more than quarterly) content are required as par Apple's guidelines to be a Newsstand app.

Subscription availability is required because background downloading via push notification makes sense only when user can purchase subscription for your periodical content. This will only make sure that user can opt-in that your app can download content in background via push notification.

This is from Apple's ios Program License Agreement. You can read it from your developer account and BTW you must have accepted this :)

3.5 You may offer in-app subscriptions for free in select territories using the In-App 
Purchase API subject to the terms of this Schedule 1, provided that the Licensed Application is 
Newsstand-enabled pursuant to section 3.7 below and You clearly and conspicuously disclose to 
users the following information regarding Your in-app subscription:
•      Title of publication or service
•      Subscription may be discontinued at any time by removing app from device
•      Links to Your Privacy Policy and Terms of Use

> 3.8 Licensed Applications offering subscription services under this Schedule 1 must be  included in Apple’s Newsstand program provided
>   that, in addition to the requirements set forth in  paragraphs 3.5,
>   3.6 and 3.7, You: • Enable the Licensed Application as a Newsstand app in the iTunes Connect tool • Authorize Apple to select “Newsstand” as
>   the Licensed Application’s secondary  category • Utilize the In-App
>   Purchase API, include any additional code, and comply with any  other
>   requirements as identified and updated from time to time in
>   Newsstand-related  documentation found in the iOS developer library
>   and the iTunes Connect Developer  Guide • Provide updated cover art
>   with each new issue  • Confirm that the content of the Licensed
>   Application is a periodical (e.g., newspaper  or magazine)

Comment: For such apps Apple want developers to create "Free Subscription". Check your iTunes account you can create auto-renew "Free" subscription + I think you are talking about background task (~10 min) to download issue while I am talking about download using NKIssueDownload which can happen even if app was not running when Newsstand notification is received (iOS launch your app in b/g).

Comment: Oh yes, i had forgotten the fact about the NKIssueDownload. Since my app is a regular one, cant it be possible say if newsstand notification is received, my app downloads the data (listing+detail) in the background by handling the notification?

Comment: regular apps cannot work on NS notifications, if your app is not running. It is iOS which take care of launching your app to background on receiving notification.

Comment: Ok so as I see it, the hurdle currently would be that the app wont be able to download the newest data on receiving a newsstand notification. However, my app can check for new data each time its manually launched and then download the data in the background and update the app while its running similar to a newsstand app would download a new issue. right?

Comment: 1) You cannot have NS app without subscription. 2) Read about background tasks from [this link] 3) You cannot achieve what is possible with NS app without NS app, this is the whole point of having NS app + to have NS app you have to follow guidelines by Apple. Best of Luck to you if you want to submit your app as NS with what you described. Off late Apple's review is random so they may pass it but then they may reject it in future anytime, which could be more damaging for you then.

Comment: here is the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: Is this answer was helpful to you ? If Yes I would appreciate if you accept it.

Comment: Yes it is helpful to an extent, i'm still looking for concrete guidelines on the kind of apps that qualify as NS apps. I will accept in due course of time :)